# Need to pick up on NAs to flag (is.na not working)

Tags: r, na

is.na is not working, however when I use `sapply(df, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))`the NAs are accounted for.

I want to detected NAs in order to flag them and create a new column based on that if an NA exists in one of two columns, the row is flagged. I.E.

```
NA   1       1
1    1       0
1    NA      1
NA   NA      1
```

Comment: Can you try `df$flag <- rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0` or `Reduce("|", lapply(df, is.na))`

Comment: Perfect, thank you @akrun.

Comment: I have a column with NAs that isn't registering albeit showing up as NA. Idea how I can coerce them to register? Is.na is not working for a column.

Comment: Would `Reduce("|", lapply(df, function(x) trimws(x) == "NA"|is.na(x)))` works

Comment: please let me know whether that picked up the NAss

Comment: can you test `grepl("NA", do.call(paste0, df))`

Comment: @akrun You did great, I solved it thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
df$flag <- rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0
```

Or another option if the `NA` elements are not picked up by `is.na` because of some strange reason

```
df$flag <- grepl("NA", do.call(paste0, df))
```

---

Or we loop over the columns with `lapply`, apply `is.na` to create a `list` of logical vectors, and `Reduce` it to a single logical vector

```
df$flag <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, is.na))
```